# DN 4.0.x and oracle : java.util.Date mapped to wrong rdbms type

Tags: datanucleus

We are migrating our application from DN 3 to DN 4.0.

We have a strange problem with the `java.util.Date` fields. They are mapped to `Date` in our *Oracle DB*.

With the older DN 3 it is mapped to `Timestamp` and we need the Oracle datatype to be `Timestamp` because `Date`(as rdbms type) cuts the milliseconds off, so the `Date` rdbms type is a bit incorrect. It is essential for us that the date is complete.

In the documentation `Timestamp` is highlighted and afaik this means it is the default rdbms datatype.

We use the current DN 4.0 version.

Someone has the same problem?

Comment: Isn't that what "sqlType" is there for you to define? You don't show what your field metadata is. I think there is some mode of SchemaTool that shows the types available, "dbinfo" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use our custom Oracle datastore adapter and with DN 4.0 the extension point name changed. But in the documentation, the old extension point is mentioned (http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/extensions/rdbms_datastore_adapter.html).

So I had to search the source code for the correct one.

If someone's there with the same problem: `org.datanucleus.store_datastoreadapter` is now: `org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datastoreadapter`